# Is a Python closure a good replacement for `__all__`?

Tags: python, closures

Is it a good idea to use a closure instead of `__all__` to limit the names exposed by a Python module? This would prevent programmers from accidentally using the wrong name for a module (`import urllib; urllib.os.getlogin()`) as well as avoiding "`from x import *`" namespace pollution as `__all__`.

```
def _init_module():
   global foo
   import bar
   def foo():
       return bar.baz.operation()
   class Quux(bar.baz.Splort): pass
_init_module(); del _init_module
```

vs. the same module using `__all__`:

```
__all__ = ['foo']
import bar
def foo():
    return bar.baz.operation()
class Quux(bar.baz.Splort): pass
```

Functions could just adopt this style to avoid polluting the module namespace:

```
def foo():
    import bar
    bar.baz.operation()
```

This might be helpful for a large package that wants to help users distinguish its API from the package's use of its and other modules' API during interactive introspection. On the other hand, maybe IPython should simply distinguish names in `__all__` during tab completion, and more users should use an IDE that allows them to jump between files to see the definition of each name.

Comment: Why don't you use `from bar import foo` in the code using this module ? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: the second bit of code does not use the first bit of code. it uses `__all__` to define the same module.

Comment: I agree with jdb: how much of a problem is all this?  Your _init_module method is very odd, and I don't understand why you would bother?  How many developers accidentally use urllib.os.getlogin, for example? Just write your code and solve the real problems.

Comment: I do not understand your explanation of the advantages of the closure.  How does the closure "prevent programmers from accidentally using the wrong name for a module"?  If someone uses `import foo as bar` then they get the name `bar`, and if they use `import foo` they get the name `foo`.  What is different about the closure?

Comment: I only have experience with this problems from working on Plone because it has so much code that no one is familiar with all of it, especially not an integrator. Before you know it, enough integrators discover a particular name through introspection and if you decide to remove e.g. `from zope.app.intid.interfaces import IIntIds` from your module then you'll break their modules. When introspecting the API from an IPython shell it's not easy to know whether any particular module-level name is supposed to be interface or implementation.

Comment: As I understand it, it is good practice in Python modules to use a leading underscore for private, implementation stuff.  Plone should change its modules so that the non-public stuff starts with an underscore.  People could still introspect the names but at least they would know they are on thin ice.

Comment: @steveha noone is going to consistently `import os as _os`. I think having IPython put the names in `__all__` first when you press `<tab>` will be a good help.

Answer (score 7):

I am a fan of writing code that is absolutely as brain-dead simple as it can be.

`__all__` is a feature of Python, added explicitly to solve the problem of limiting what names are made visible by a module.  When you use it, people immediately understand what you are doing with it.

Your closure trick is very nonstandard, and if I encountered it, I would not immediately understand it.  You would need to put in a long comment to explain it, and then you would need to put in another long comment to explain why you did it that way instead of using `__all__`.

EDIT: Now that I understand the problem a little better, here is an alternate answer.

In Python it is considered good practice to prefix private names with an underscore in a module.  If you do `from the_module_name import *` you will get all the names that do not start with an underscore.  So, rather than the closure trick, I would prefer to see correct use of the initial-underscore idiom.

Note that if you use the initial underscore names, you don't even need to use `__all__`.

Comment: The problem is that `__all__` only helps when you use `from x import *` which is something you shouldn't do anyway, while the closure trick provides for very concise introspection. In Plone, where any given name is defined somewhere among hundreds of eggs, tens of thousands of python files and millions of lines of code, there's only a small chance that you will actually read my code and have the opportunity to notice either the `__all__` or a closure.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `from x import *` is that it can hide `NameErrors` which makes trivial bugs hard to track down. "namespace pollution" means adding stuff to the namespace that you have no idea where it came from.

Which is kind of what your closure does too. Plus it might confuse IDEs, outlines, pylint and the like.

Using the "wrong" name for a module is not a real problem either. Module objects are the same from wherever you import them. If the "wrong" name disappears (after a update) it should be clear why and motivate the programmer to do it properly next time. But it doesn't cause bugs.

Comment: `from x import *` should only be used in the REPL. Brittle code isn't a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm beginning to understand this issue a bit more.  The closure really does allow for hiding private stuff.  Here's a simple example.

Without the closure:

```
# module named "foo.py"
def _bar():
    return 5

def foo():
    return _bar() - 2
```

With the closure:

```
# module named "fooclosure.py"
def _init_module():
    global foo
    def _bar():
        return 5

    def foo():
        return _bar() - 2

_init_module(); del _init_module
```

Sample of usage:

```
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_bar', 'foo']
>>>
>>> import fooclosure
>>> dir(fooclosure)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'foo']
>>>
```

This is actually disturbingly subtle.  In the first case, function `foo()` simply has a reference to the name `_bar()`, and if you were to remove `_bar()` from the name space, `foo()` would stop working.  `foo()` looks up `_bar()` each and every time it runs.

In contrast, the closure version of `foo()` works without `_bar()` existing in the name space.  I'm not even certain *how* it works... is it holding a reference to the function object created for `_bar()`, or is it holding a reference to a name space that still exists, such that it can look up the name `_bar()` and find it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators for a more normal use of a closure. In Python 2.x, foo() keeps _bar in foo.func_closure